# Python - Words in string affect outcome

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and I am trying to develop a phone troubleshoot program where I ask the user what is wrong with their device, and if my program detects the word 'wet' or 'water' it will reply with an outcome. Another example would be 'screen is cracked'. I am having a problem that if I input 'My screen is cracked'. My code does not detect it. Any help appreciated!

Snippet of my code:

```
print(60 * '-')
print('Could you describe what is wrong with your device?')
print(60 * '-')
time.sleep(1)
user_problem = input('')

if user_problem in ('water', 'waterdamage', 'rain', 'toilet', 'pool', 'sea',     'ocean', 'river',):
    print('WATERDAMAGE VARAIBLE')

elif user_problem in ('screen', 'cracked', 'shattered', 'smashed',):
    print('SCREEN VARIABLE')
```

Comment: you are trying to match `My screen is cracked` to each item in your tuple... Try to split up the input and match the words individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`userproblem` is your whole user's input. You are checking if it belongs to a tuple with those keywords. So, if the input is `"My phone is wet"`, this string does not belong to `('water', 'waterdamage', 'rain', 'toilet', 'pool', 'sea', 'ocean', 'river',)` since it's not equal to any of these words. Same problem in the second `if`.

The correct solution is to ask if *any* of these words is contained in the input, which is quite the opposite. You would have something like:

```
userproblem_words = userproblem.split(' ')

water_related_words = ('water', 'waterdamage', 'rain', 'toilet', 'pool', 'sea', 'ocean', 'river')
if (any([(word in water_related_words) for word in userproblem_words])):
    print('WATERDAMAGE VARIABLE')

break_related_words = ('screen', 'cracked', 'shattered', 'smashed')
elif (any([word in userproblem for word in break_related_words])):
    print('SCREEN VARIABLE')
```

Or, if you don't like the list comprehension's readability in this case, you can use a plain `for`:

```
water_related_words = ('water', 'waterdamage', 'rain', 'toilet', 'pool', 'sea', 'ocean', 'river')
break_related_words = ('screen', 'cracked', 'shattered', 'smashed')

for word in userproblem.split(' '):
    if word in water_related_words:
        print('WATERDAMAGE VARIABLE')
        break

    elif word in break_related_words:
        print('SCREEN VARIABLE')
        break
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it helped me to understand how it all works!!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but say I input 'My screen is cracked', how can I prevent my program from printing SCREEN VARIABLE twice? @lucasnadalutti

Comment: Add a `break` after each `print`. Your program will leave the loop, which guarantees nothing will be printed more than once.

Comment: @lucasnadalutti I must add that your approach is unfair. You answered the question partially and started adding bits of code to finally get upvotes and solution mark. My answer was correct before yours yet you are the one getting the points. If that is the way system works I am very displeased.

Comment: @Boris this makes no sense at all. The time between our posts was almost the same, and I didn't copy anything from your answer. Instead, I kindly went to your answer's comments to alert you that your solution had a flaw, which I myself had in my original one **and** fixed before telling you about it. The other edits were to add more relevant information which I honestly can't see in which way affects you.

Comment: Nevertheless, I won't extend this discussion since this is much more of a mutual helping and learning forum than a reputation-fighting-and-winning arena. I am the one displeased that I'm having this kind of discussion here in first place. But again, I won't extend it and I wish you well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your approach, here is an example how you can do it:

```
print (60 * '-')
print ('Could you describe what is wrong with your device?')
print (60 * '-')
time.sleep(1)
userproblem = input('')

water = ['water', 'waterdamage', 'rain', 'toilet', 'pool', 'sea',     'ocean', 'river']
screen = ['screen', 'cracked', 'shattered', 'smashed']
for item in water:
    if item in userproblem.split(' '):
        print('WATERDAMAGE VARIABLE')
        break
for item in screen:
    if item in userproblem.split(' '):
        print('SCREEN VARIABLE')
        break
```

Comment: I figured this approach as well but it's not failsafe. "I lost my device in Swan**sea**" would print `WATERDAMAGE VARIABLE`. Turns out that these words can only match a whole word from the user's input, simply being contained by the input is not enough.

Comment: That is easy to fix. Just change `if item in userproblem` into `if item in userproblem.split(' ')`.